# Issue with Listing Files During Load Event

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a program that lists all the files you have in a certain(select-able) directory with the file extension ".pdf" and allows the user send these files to a network drive.

For some reason it works great on every computer except for one and takes about 10 minutes to load.

Is there any way to see what is happening on their side and why it might be hanging up.

Comment: Do they experience the same slowness if they go into the directory with Explorer to list the files? In that case the problem is outside of your program (e.g. a slow network disk).

Comment: If they use Explorer they load the directory within a couple seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user had a vast amount of files on his directory therefore searching all these file was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't list the files in Form_Load event. On a slow fragmented disk it can take longer to list the files.

Do it in BackgroundWorker